# Best way to manage two separate remote repositories - github and heroku

Tags: git, github, heroku

I just built a web server using heroku, because I get it free being a student. The project started with a github repository which was simple enough, but now I have the heroku and github repository. The heroku/master branch is my deploy/ production repo and this is where I would like to push to all final changes to go live. However I would also like to have my github repository. I am fairly new to git and am still on the learning curve and don't quiet understand what these commands do. I understand that heroku allows for the master branch of the github repo to be the deploy, except this is not what I would like to do.

**For example**
 If I have add some or fix some code that I don't immediately want to be deployed but I want it on my github repo, what should I do? -- how do I make sure that I'm on the github repo, add to it, commit to it, and push to it.

Then after I have added some code to the github repo and I would like to push all the code from my github repo onto the heroku repo how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need are git branches.

When you clone a GitHub repo your GitHub repo remote will be called `origin`. You push to the `master` branch on your GitHub repo (`origin` remote`) via

```
git push origin master
```

You can add another remote. E.g. Heroku:

```
git remote add heroku <git_url>
```

Your Heroku remote is called `heroku`. You can push to it via:

```
git push heroku master
```

You mentioned that you want to keep your `master` as a production/deployment. `master` is simultaneously a git branch. You can branch off it.

```
git branch dev # this creates the dev branch
git checkout dev # this switches to the dev branch
```

You can now develop on the `dev` branch and push this to GitHub.

```
git push origin dev
```

When you are satisfied with your `dev` branch you can merge it into master and push it.

```
git checkout master # switch to master branch
git merge dev # take the commits from dev branch and put it into master branch
git push origin master # push to GitHub
git push heroku master # push to Heroku
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed!